# Cannot access 'Directive' before initialization when exported in index.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

When I export my Directive in the index.ts i get the Cannot "access 'SomeDirective' before initialization" error.
When I import the Directive normally the code works.

I have a BaseDirective

```
export class BaseDirective implements OnInit {

  protected baseModel: BaseModel = 
  { id: '', type: Type.Undefined };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // do base stuff
  }

  protected baseFunction() {
    console.log('gets overwritten');
  }

}
```

And the Second directive extending it

```
export class SomeDirective extends BaseDirective {

  protected customerDetailsService = inject(CustomerDetailsService);

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  protected override baseFunction(): void {
    // do something
  }

}
```

the index.ts looks like this

```
export * from './base/base.directive';
export * from './some/some.directive';
export * from './base/base.model';
```

When I try to use the SomeDirective in a Component extend and import it via
@directives/index i get the error.
But via
import { SomeDirective } from '@directives/some/some.directive';
it works fine

I am using the standalone approach so there is no module in the project.
Every Component and Directive has the 'standalone': true flag.

I don't understand what the index.ts has to do with initialization. All I found so far was that the error is linked to circular dependency but since I don't use modules I doubt that that is the case

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on without the actual code that throws the error. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can use [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to make one.

Comment: How are you importing the base directive in the `SomeOtherDirective`? If you are importing through the alias '@directives/index' it can be due to that. Try using the relative path

Comment: If you want to reuse behaviour you can use the new [directive composition api](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api)

Comment: @MikeS. I tried to make a simple example with Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhgi4p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: @hawks I imported the Base or Broadcast Directive not with '@directives'. When I use the Some ( or ProblemDirective in the Stackblitz Example ) with its relative path everthing works fine. But the moment I add the SomeDirective in the index.ts of the directives folder I get the error